# Unexpected Behavior IIS 7 running classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

There may be two separate issues occurring, or it may be a single issue.

1.
When I go to my site running classic asp.  The first page will load with no problem.  When I click the second page I get "500 internal server error  There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."  When I refresh the page it will work fine (i.e loads as expected).  This error happens most frequently when I have not used the site for a period of time (e.g. 5 to 24 hrs).

2.
After that, all of the pages work with out issue except 2.  The 2 that do not work have the below error message.

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a004c'
>
> Path not found
>
> /fcLog.asp, line 153

I am confused by this second error because all of the asp files are in the same directory.  The ones that work and this one.  I believe if one asp file works in this directory then all of them should as well.  I wonder if these 2 error messages are related.  I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: The second error is telling you that you have a line of code in your `fcLog.asp` file that's trying to access a file path that cannot be found. So open your `fcLog.asp` file and look at line 153 and see if you can figure out why (or edit your question and post it there). If you're trying to log every page access using your `fcLog.asp` file, it may very well be your problem #1 as well.

Comment: are both pages in same folder?

Comment: plz show some source code. does fcLog.asp include some additional files? may be fcLog.asp has some condition -- include or do not include file, and that is why at first time you get error, but at second time everything is fine.

Comment: @Zam: note that asp can't do conditional includes, or more accurately, the includes happen long before any code is looked at. Thus, whatever the problem is, it's *not* that an include file is sometimes missing, sometimes not.